# Understanding copy-initialization in C++, compared to explicit initialization

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Why does the first commented line compile correctly, whereas the second doesn't?

Why can `a` be given itself as a constructor argument, but `b` can't?
Aren't the two doing the same thing?

```
class Foo { Foo &operator =(Foo const &); /* Disable assignment */ };

int main()
{
    Foo a = a;  // OK
    Foo  b(b);  // error C2065: 'b' : undeclared identifier
}
```

---

### Update

Since it seems like it's compiler-dependent, it seems like the problem is more severe than I thought.
So I guess another part of the question is, is the following code valid or no?

It gives an error in GCC but Visual C++ executes it just fine.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    { int *i(&i); }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Both work (error-wise) on GCC 4.7.2 and Clang 3.2.

Comment: @chris: Oh weird, I was using Visual C++. In that case, which one is right?!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd wager a guess on GCC and Clang over MSVC almost any day. At least it narrows down the problem a bit.

Comment: Actually both should compile. A code like `int a=a+100;` and `int a(a+100);` is fine from syntax point of view. They might invoke UB depending on whether they're created in static storage duration or automatic storage duration.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I edited the title because it is not assignment initialization. The form `A a = x` is called copy-initialization, and `A a(x)` is called direct initialization.

Comment: perhaps vc++ doesnt lookup the identifier again after having done disambiguation lookup of the identifier to determine whether it is a type or not (if it is a type, it will be a function parameter declaration).

Comment: What has the assignment operator got to do with anything in the example? And I would never describe this as "severe" because it only affects really silly code.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: The assignment operator is there because I started having doubts about whether it might be somehow affecting things. And regarding it being "silly", I think it could have been perfectly legitimate code, nothing silly about it...

Comment: When have you _intentionally_ used a variable in its own initializer in perfectly legitimate code, rather than it being an accident?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I have *intentionally* written code like `int i(i)` in order to capture a copy of `i` defined in the **outer** scope, if that's what you mean. Obviously I didn't know they're referring the same variable until after I asked this question...

Comment: Well stop doing that and get a better compiler ;-) In any case, I maintain the problem is not "severe" because it's [well known](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3173462/981959)

Comment: @JonathanWakely I have *intentionally* written this quiz question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309042/is-this-self-initialization-valid :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first code, both declarations should compile. GCC is right there. Visual C++ Compiler has bug.

And in the second code, the inner declaration should **not** compile. GCC is right there too, and VC++ is wrong.

**GCC is right in both cases**.

A code like `int a=a+100;` and `int a(a+100);` is fine from *syntax* point of view. They might invoke undefined behavior depending on whether they're created in *static storage duration* or *automatic storage duration*.

```
int a = a + 100; //well-defined. a is initialized to 100
                 //a on RHS is statically initialized to 0
                 //then a on LHS is dynamically initialized to (0+100).
void f()
{
   int b = b + 100; //undefined-behavior. b on RHS is uninitialized

   int a = a + 50; //which `a` is on the RHS? previously declared one?
                   //No. `a` on RHS refers to the newly declared one.
                   //the part `int a` declares a variable, which hides 
                   //any symbol with same name declared in outer scope, 
                   //then `=a+50` is the initializer part.
                   //since a on RHS is uninitialized, it invokes UB
}
```

Please read the comments associated with each declaration above.

Note that variables with *static storage duration* is statically initialized to zero at compile time, and if they've initializer, then they're dynamically initialized *also* at runtime. But variables of POD types with *automatic storage duration* are not statically initialized.

For more detail explanation on *static initialization vs dynamic initialization*, see this:

- [What is dynamic initialization of object in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945897/what-is-dynamic-intialization-of-object-in-c)

Comment: What if `a` is previously defined as something else, like, say, a `class`? Is it still fine?

Comment: @Mehrdad: That is redeclaration, no?

Comment: Maybe in a different scope, yeah. But my question is, would the `a` on the right-hand side be referring to the old `a` or the new `a`?

Comment: @Mehrdad: It refers to the new `a` : the part `int a` declares a variable, which hides any symbol with same name declared in outer scope, then `=a+100` is the initializer part.

Comment: Huh... +1 interesting, thanks for the answer. On another note, this "would you like to move this discussion to chat?" thing is popping up waaaaay too early...

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, as you note, the behavior is undefined even though the syntax is okay.  A compiler is therefore permitted to refuse the code (the undefined behavior must be guaranteed however; it is here, but it wouldn't be if the invalid initializations were never actually executed).

Your second example has a type error: A declaration is visible as soon as its declarator is seen, and in particular it is visible in its own initializer.  MSVC++ delays the visibility: That's a known non-conformance issue in that compiler.  E.g., with the EDG compiler (which has a Microsoft mode):

```
$ ./cfe --strict x.c
"x.c", line 4: error: a value of type "int **" cannot be used to initialize an
          entity of type "int *"
      { int *i(&i); }
               ^

1 error detected in the compilation of "x.c".
$ ./cfe --microsoft x.c
"x.c", line 4: warning: variable "i" was declared but never referenced
      { int *i(&i); }
             ^
```

Comment: thanks for the insight again :-). now i know it is a known bug :-)