Declaring variable based on itself in C++ somehow works, but how?
Contrary to all my expectations, the following code works:
#include <stdio.h>

int y = y;
int main() {
    int x = x;
    printf("Hello World%d|%d|\n", x, y);

    return 0;
}

‍‍‍
It compiles and runs successfully, with different values for x being printed and y always being equal to zero (which is the same behaviour when compared to just putting int y; and int x; instead of int y = y; and int x=x;, respectively).
On onlinegdb, it works when I select C++, C++14, C++17, C++20, or C++23, but fails (does not compile) when I select the C language: ‍‍‍‍‍‍

error: initializer element is not constant

By the way, if I replace int x = x; with int x = x*x;, it appears to have the same behaviour as doing int x; and then printing x*x.
I'm extremely curious about how this works, or why it is even allowed. What does the compiler even do? I couldn't find any information about this when I tried to search about it.

Some compilers take int x = x; to mean “I am deliberately leaving x uninitialized, so do not give me warnings in later code about it possibly being used uninitialized.” The error you are getting about the initializer not being constant is due to different rules in C and C++ about what initializers can be.

In C++ this is undefined behaviour because you are using a variable before it has been initialised. Working (whatever you mean by that) is one possible consequence of undefined behaviour.

A better example that isn't instant undefined behavior due to using an uninitialized value is void* p = (void*) &p;.

This comes from C: variable initialization’s scope includes the variable being initialized (because it is already declared). It is occasionally useful, but I have never needed to use it.

BTW, I just answered another Q with the same issue. Is someone teaching a class somewhere showing students weird things like int x = x?

@EricPostpischil, interesting idiom (if it were not UB), T t = t; seems more deliberate than T t; which might or might not initialize the variable depending on the type of T.

one can do     int x = (x = 5); for that matter ;). These cases are covered by -Wsequence-point and -Wuninitialized (both of which are active under -Wall in GCC). https://godbolt.org/z/Kex5z9zWE note that there is no complain for the global variable, because it was already 0 before you even looked at it.

@Dúthomhas   I'm hoping, but not holding my breath, that someone is teaching about things that students should avoid using, unless they know exactly what they are doing.    This particular example is one for which language lawyers don't always agree on what happens and, worse, the standards (as well as interpretation of the standards) have changed over time.

It Lua, the equivalent syntax local x = x; as a different meaning, which is much more useful (and reasonable). It means copy the existing x variable from previous scope (possibly a global variable) into a new local variable x variable, that will hide the previous one starting on next line, up to the end of the scope. I wish C and C++ did the same.

@prapin Alas, that would be cool. As it is it is only possible in C++ with explicit scope: int x = ::x;

'y' is initialized to zero because it is at file scope, that is done before the assignment to y, so the assignment is, in effect, a no-op.
x get random values because it is frame-based and frame-based variables do not get automatic initialization the way file-scoped objects do.

This is UB for non-global variables, at least in C++: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67662535/2752075 For global variables it may or may not be UB, the standard isn't being entirely clear: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67991829/2752075

Variables in global/file scope are stored in static storage, and static storage is initialized at program startup. Such variables are constant-initialized if an initializer is specified, otherwise they are zero-initialized

int x = x; is not a random value.  It's undefined behavior.  (Because I compile with warnings on, and treat warnings as errors, it doesn't compile on my machine since it causes warning: variable 'x' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized].  Disabling warnings, alas, UBSan didn't catch it.  :sadpanda:)

int y = y; -- there is no assignment to y. y is being initialized. int y; y = y; would be an assignment.
